# Can I get a report on missing XML documentation

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015, stylecop, ghostdoc

I am trying out GhostDoc, StyleCop, CodeIt.Right, FXCop etc to find a streamlined way of adding both autogenerated XML-Comments in C# code as well as updating existing comments in case parameters changed for example.

GhostDoc  Pro seems to work well, except for the fact that I cant get a report on coverage, or at least the classes that completely lack documentation.

How can I get such a report?

Comment: I stopped using autogenerated comments when I realised that if they could be autogenerated from the class, method or parameter names, then they were pointless... However, if you turn on XML comment generation then you should get a compiler warning for public methods, classes and properties that don't have XML documentation.

Comment: Yes I know, I get  "warning CS1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member", however I dont know right now how to extract only those warnings from the Build output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned, GhostDoc will help you with this; you just may need a newer version or the right edition.

You can use the GhostDoc Pro Documentation Maintenance feature in the v5 - it will help you find auto-generated docs, find classes/methods that are missing documentation, as well as those that require updating (method signature out of sync) or editing. Here is more info on the v5 features - http://submain.com/blog/ReleasedGhostDocV50.aspx

You mentioned you also use CodeIt.Right - you want to turn On rule GE00005 - Externally visible types and members should have XML comments (Type, Member -> Should have XML comments). You can also export the list in VS or generate it in your build.

Both GhostDoc and CodeIt.Right will generate XML comment templates for the missing docs but, of course, you'd want to edit them afterward.